# I can't use get package on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pup

I clone this app from `github` and when i try to get packages to it it gave me that error

Because `my_flutter_ui_challenges` depends on `fluttery_seekbar` any which doesn't exist

> (could not find package `fluttery_seekbar` at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.

dose any one know how to fix this

Comment: Yes, remove the line with the `fluttery_seekbar` dependency in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Looking on pub.dev confirms that the fluttery_seekbar package does, indeed, not exist there. Have you looked at the `pubspec.yaml` file to see what the dependency is? Perhaps its a local dependency that the author of the github app didn't include in the repository. It would help if you could say which github repository you cloned was.

Comment: I have the same error. I copied this repository: https://github.com/Alameen688/pomodoro

Answer (score 1):

try to resolve by running

```
flutter upgrade
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

Package was removed. More info here: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2853

Still some apps depend on it: 
https://libraries.io/pub/fluttery_seekbar

You can still download copy of it here: https://github.com/ganeshbehera/fluttery_seekbar/blob/b60704358fd27ae2f8ac41f8e29d87454d9103dc/fluttery_seekbar-master.zip

How to install it manually is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15817
(add version number to folder name, in the same way as other folder are named)

However you will also need fluttery 0.0.8 package which I was not able to find